# Python 3.3 cx_freeze weird error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze, python-3.3

So, here's my problem.

I'm making a game in Pygame and Python 3.3, using Ubuntu 12.10.  Fine.  I'm gonna bundle a bunch of Python scripts into one executable, then distribute it.  Also fine.  I'm going with cx_freeze, because since I'm using Python 3 I have no other options.

This is where my problem comes in.  I've Googled around, but haven't seen anything like it.  My `setup.py` is as follows:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

includes = ['sys', 'pygame.display', 'pygame.event', 'pygame.mixer', 'core', 'game']

build_options = {
                 'optimize' : 2,
                 'compressed': True,
                 'packages': ['pygame', 'core', 'game'],
                 'includes': includes,
                 'path': sys.path + ['core', 'game'],
                 }

executable = Executable('__init__.py',
                        copyDependentFiles=True,
                        targetDir='dist',
                        )

setup(name='Invasodado',
      version='0.8',
      description='wowza!',
      options = {'build_exe': build_options},
      executables=[executable])
```

My `__init__.py` is as follows:

```
from sys import argv

import pygame.display
import pygame.event
import pygame.mixer

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.init()
pygame.font.init()

from core import gsm

#Omitted for brevity
```

The rest of my code (including the full `__init__.py`) can be found at https://github.com/CorundumGames/Invasodado, in case it's relevant.

I get a long-ass stack trace, which can be found here http://pastebin.com/Aej05wGE .  The last 10 lines of it is this;

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 421, in _RunHook
    method(self, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/hooks.py", line 454, in load_scipy
    finder.IncludePackage("scipy.lib")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 536, in IncludePackage
    self._ImportAllSubModules(module, deferredImports)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 211, in _ImportAllSubModules
    recursive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/dist-packages/cx_Freeze/finder.py", line 209, in _ImportAllSubModules
    if subModule.path and recursive:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'
```

In case it's relevant, I'm using Pydev and Eclipse.  Now, the last line stands out because Googling it reveals nothing.  I have no idea where `subModule` could have become `None`, and I can't easily check because cx_freeze has shit documentation.

I've never really used cx_freeze or distutils before, so I don't know what the hell I'm doing!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At a first look: calling your launcher script `__init__.py` is a bit odd. Normally you have a script named `invasidado.py` (or whatever) which imports a package and calls a function from it. That might be hitting an untested corner case in cx_Freeze.

Comment: (Couldn't reproduce in Python 3.2, Ubuntu 12.10, with current master cx_Freeze)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having dug into this, it's a bug in cx_Freeze, that can only hit when you have more than one Python version since [PEP 3149](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#pep-3149-abi-version-tagged-so-files) installed - i.e. it wouldn't have come up before 3.3.

I've filed a bug report for it: https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/22/error-when-scanning-for-modules-with-a

In the mean time, you can probably avoid the problem by using Python 3.2 for now, because that's the default in Ubuntu 12.10. Python 3.3 will be the default in 13.04.

Comment: Hot damn, it actually builds!  Thanks!  EXCEPT.  The compiled binary doesn't run.  My new setup.py is at http://pastebin.com/QEcnnvQi, and the error message from Python 3.2.3 is just `Fatal Python error: cannot get zipimporter instance; Aborted (core dumped)
`

Comment: Are you running the binary from the same folder as `library.zip`? I've just tried, and I don't see that error (I see another one because it can't find the `sfx` folder to load a sound file).

Comment: I am now, but I still get an error.  This pastebin comes if I run `./__init__` with all of pygame's so's in the same directory: http://pastebin.com/k4SZ2FPp

Comment: Is there a `pygame._view.<something>` file there?

Comment: No.  I assume that's an internal support module, so I'm gonna try adding that to my `setup.py`.

Comment: It worked!  I had to import a few other modules in `setup.py`, and change my uses of `quit()` to `sys.exit()` for some reason, but it worked!  Thank you so much!